# BI PUBLISHER RTF template COLUMN TRIM ISSUE

Tags: rtf, oracle-xml-publisher

I have some issue  RTF templete in a column. column have length 3 in the backend but when i took output IN excel sheet it shows length 5.
i have used  and  but not working.
Is there any solution in sql query or in xml code?
Thanks.